# Prove that if a good is inferior, it is also a Giffen good

Tags: microeconomics

This was asked in my online midterm test, and I proved it using the fact that a Giffen good and an inferior good behave in the same manner with respect to increase or decrease in purchasing power. Although I know that there exist inferior goods that are also giffen, I'm not able to find a rigorous proof.

Thank you for your help.

Edit 1 :As pointed out in the comments, I feel its necessary to clarify some aspects of the question Firstly, the proof can be mathematical or verbal with the support of a graph. Secondly, this is the original question, it was not given the other way round. The question was preceded by the statement "A Giffen Good is a highly inferior good" and then the question was given.

Comment: Are you sure it is not the other way around? A Giffen good must be an inferior good, but not the other way around.

Comment: You may like to change the title as pointed out by @MichaelGreinecker. An inferior goods is that which has negative income effect. When the income effect is negative enough to overshadow substitution effect (in magnitude) it becomes a giffen good. So every giffen good is inferior but the opposite is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in one of the comments, a descriptive answer to the question is available [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/25323/difference-between-giffen-and-inferior-goods-why-arent-all-inferior-goods-giff). However, here OP has asked for a rigorous proof. It is not true that if a good is inferior, it is also Giffen. On the contrary, if a good is Giffen, it is inferior. Here's a proof for this. Note that I am using some of the properties directly as including their proofs will make the answer undesirably long.

First some definitions:

Let $h_i(\mathbf p,u)$ and $x_i(\mathbf p, m)$ be the compensated (or Hicksian) demand function and Marshallian demand function for good $i$, respectively. Here, $\mathbf p$ is the price vector, $u: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be the utility function meeting all the regularity conditions (quasi-concavity, continuity, etc.), and $m$ is the income.

Formally,

\begin{align}
\mathbf h(\mathbf p,u) = \arg \min\limits_{\mathbf x} \, \mathbf {p \cdot x} \\
\text{such that } u(\mathbf x) \geq u
\end{align}

Further, let $e(\mathbf p, u)$ be the expenditure minimizing function for a given minimum utility level $u$. So, $e(\mathbf p, u) = \mathbf{p\cdot h}(\mathbf p,u)$.

For Marshallian demand function:

\begin{align}
\mathbf x(\mathbf p,m) = \arg \max\limits_{\mathbf x} \, u(\mathbf x) \\
\text{such that } \mathbf {p \cdot x} \leq m
\end{align}

Now, from duality we have:

\begin{align}
h_i(\mathbf p,u) \equiv x_i(\mathbf p,e(\mathbf p, u))  \\
\end{align}

Differentiating this equation w.r.t $p_i$:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial h_i(\mathbf p,u)}{\partial p_i} & = \frac{\partial x_i(\mathbf p,e(\mathbf p, u))}{\partial p_i} + \frac{\partial x_i(\mathbf p,e(\mathbf p, u))}{\partial e}\frac{\partial e(\mathbf p, u)}{\partial p_i}  \\
\end{align}

In the terms, $ \frac{\partial x_i(\mathbf p,e(\mathbf p, u))}{\partial p_i}, \frac{x_i(\mathbf p,e(\mathbf p, u))}{\partial e}$, $e$ is not really being treated as a function, so we replace with $m$, giving:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial h_i(\mathbf p,u)}{\partial p_i} & = \frac{\partial x_i(\mathbf p,m)}{\partial p_i} + \frac{\partial x_i(\mathbf p,m)}{\partial m}\frac{\partial e(\mathbf p, u)}{\partial p_i}  \\
\end{align}

Rearranging gives:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial x_i(\mathbf p,m)}{\partial p_i} & =  \frac{\partial h_i(\mathbf p,u)}{\partial p_i} - \frac{\partial x_i(\mathbf p,m)}{\partial m}\frac{\partial e(\mathbf p, u)}{\partial p_i}  \tag1
\end{align}

Now, note the following properties:

(1) From convexity of preferences (or quasi-concavity of utility function), $h_i(\mathbf p, u)$ is non-increasing in $\mathbf p$. Therefore, we have that:

$$\frac{\partial h_i(\mathbf p,u)}{\partial p_i} \leq 0$$

(2) $e(\mathbf p, u)$ is non-decreasing in $\mathbf p$. So we have:

$$\frac{\partial e(\mathbf p, u)}{\partial p_i} \geq 0$$

Using these in $(1)$, we can say:

$$\frac{\partial x_i(\mathbf p,m)}{\partial p_i} > 0 \text{     only if}\,\, \,\, \frac{\partial x_i(\mathbf p,m)}{\partial m} < 0$$

---

A side note: it seems that at some places (in some comments and the descriptive answer sited above) that a Giffen good is the one that does not follow **Law of demand**. This is not strictly speaking true. The law of demand pertains to *Hicksian* demand not the Marshallian demand. As it can be seen in the proof, $h_i(\mathbf p, u)$ is **always** non-increasing in $p_i$, but $x_i(\mathbf p, m)$ may not necessarily be. So the law of demand always hold under the regularity conditions on preferences.

Comment: Interestingly, this answer has had 3 downvotes and 2 upvotes. But none of the downvoters have left a comment citing any reason, something which is usually a practice on other stack exchange sites.